# Windows Qt Invoke batch file and exit the App

Tags: c++, qt, batch-file, window

I am developing an application in Windows8 using Qt, where I need to create an updater for it. I have Already  wrote the update downloader part, and an update script to replace all the previous content with newly downloaded data.

Now I need to execute the bat file from the application itself, and exit the app before the script get executed, because the script going to remove all the dlls and application binary currently I am running.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks 
Haris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `QProcess::startDetached` to run an instance of command prompt with the batch file as the argument in a new process and detach from it. After that you should exit the application :

```
QProcess::startDetached("cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/c" << "path\\to\\mybat.bat");
qApp->quit();
```